# Why am I not being able to send an email out using php?

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why am I have these errors when i am trying to send an email using php? Thank you in advance.

> Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Did you even TRY To read the message? it tells you the problem...

Comment: -1. This question shows a failure to do a bare minimum of your own thinking before submitting a question to StackOverflow. The error message very clearly says exactly what the problem is and you've provided no information that would let us tell you anything more than "You're missing a From: header."

Comment: but i had already inserted it inside my code :( it i didn't indicate inside myphp , and it doesnt work , i still can understand , but now i'd already inserted it inside but it is not working :(

Comment: $admin_email = "example@example.com";
  $recipient = $Fetch_accountantEmail;
  $subject = "invoice";
  $headers = "From: example@example.com" . "\r\n" .
  
         
  $message = "The invoice for the month has been received . ";

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `From` header. Please read the documentation on the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.